# Conditional drupal_add_css and _js are adding code to every page

Tags: 6, theming, javascript

I am trying to add a CSS and JS files when a certain content type is being viewed (Drupal 6).  The problem is that the code is being added to every page.

I have tried this first, included in template.php:

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook) {
  $node = $vars['node'];
  if ($node->type == 'mytype') {
        drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . "/css/mytpess.css");

        drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . "/javascripts/jquery.masonry.min.js");
        drupal_add_js("$(document).ready(function(){
                          $('.node').masonry({
                            itemSelector: '.field-type-flexifield'
                          });
                        });",'inline');
  }
}
```

Then I moved it out of there and placed it in node-mytype.tpl.php:

```
drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . "/css/mytpess.css");

drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . "/javascripts/jquery.masonry.min.js");
drupal_add_js("$(document).ready(function(){
                  $('.node').masonry({
                    itemSelector: '.field-type-flexifield'
                  });
                });",'inline');
```

But either way it gets added to every page.  How can I resolve this?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that code. have you cleared your site cache lately?

Comment: There's nothing in either snippet that is telling the script to only be added on the front page.

Comment: I don't think he wants it to be added to the front page :).

Comment: Aaah, silly me!  I'm not sure WHERE I got front page from :-p

Comment: Dumb question - have you cleared the theme registry?

Comment: Yes, and actually over the past few weeks I've noticed that I need to clear the cache several times, otherwise the system uses an OLDER css cache file... I'm guessing it's related

Answer (score 3):

If you are adding drupal_add_css or_js in phptemplate_preprocess_node,

1. First fetch all the added css in one variable and assign this for $styles value
2. Same like css you need to do for js also.

Here with see the sample code below

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook) { $node = $vars['node']; 
if ($node->type == 'mytype') {
    drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . "/css/mytpess.css");

    drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . "/javascripts/jquery.masonry.min.js");
    drupal_add_js("$(document).ready(function(){
                      $('.node').masonry({
                        itemSelector: '.field-type-flexifield'
                      });
                    });",'inline'); 
 }
$css = drupal_add_css();
$scripts = drupal_add_js();
$vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css($css);
$vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $scripts);
}
```

Comment: `$vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css();` should do it.

Comment: drupal_add_css() return array of css added in that site.

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!node.php/function/hook_view/6 hook_view in custom module to do this.

For example if your module name is "example" then function should be

```
function example_view($node, FALSE, TRUE) {
  if ($node->type == "mytype") {
    drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . "/css/mytpess.css");
    drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . "/javascripts/jquery.masonry.min.js");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't `template_preprocess_node()` too late? Try using `template_preprocess_page()` instead. `$variables['node']->type` as usual.

```
function template_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['node'], $vars['node']->type) && $vars['node']->type === 'mytype') {
    //ADD_JS
    //ADD_CSS
  }
}
```

**Edit:** as a sidenote, `template_preprocess_page` should be renamed to `THEME_NAME_preprocess_page` or `MODULE_NAME_preprocess_page`. Depending on where you place that function.